# How do I get the view controller that trigger the segue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How do I get the view controller that trigger the segue without using delegates. And without set it in prepareForSegue. And both view controllers will be embedded in their navigation controllers.

I would like to get that view controller from the view controller that is presented. I know that this is not the iOS way, since the iOS way is using delegates.

But I would appreciate how to get the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main concept here that you should understand. First one is navigation controller, which pushes new view controller on the top of its viewControllers stack and the second one is a simple modal view controller, which simply presents a new view controller.

If you are using navigation controller and you push a new view controller on to the stack, you could use the following methods to get the view controller which pushed it,

```
if let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers, viewControllers.count > 1 {

    let presentingViewController = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]
}
```

And, in case of modal view controllers, you could simply use **presentingViewController** property on UIViewController. Also notice that presentingViewController is optional, which means that if this view controller is not **presentedViewController** of the viewcontroller which presents it, then, ***presentingViewController*** becomes nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the entire stack of `UIViewControllers` from the `UINavigationController`:

```
let viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers
```

You can read back from the last and back:

```
if let viewController = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - x] {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Where `x` is an Integer to define how far back the stack you want to go.